# live video streaming from url in javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to show live streaming video from url in javafx. I am using webview.

It is showing only text in that webpage. It is not showing live video streaming. Please suggest me a way to do that.

```
public class A extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().load("http://192.168.0.143:8000/");
    
    VBox vbox = new VBox(webView); 
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}